# HDFS Rest File size limiit?

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

Having a weird issue with HDFS Rest API.  When I send a file 1gb or larger I am getting back a 408 Request body incomplete.  Is there an upper limit to file sizes over the Rest interface?

Comment: You might want to look at NFS Gateway instead

Comment: After much research, that actually looks like the best option,  Thanks!